# Use Python to Teleport Mouse in Blender Window (like when scaling)

Tags: python, video-sequence-editor

I am making improvements to the [VSE_Transform_Tools](https://github.com/doakey3/VSE_Transform_Tools) addon and I'd like to know if there is a way for me to use python to make the mouse jump to the other side of the screen when scaling or grabbing as seen in the 3d view:

[image]

Currently my addon does not have this behavior, as you can see:

[image]

Comment: If I may add I'm certain blender already does that. You shouldn't need to do anything with the code.

Comment: I have added another image to show how this is a problem for my addon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your operator should include the following in the bl_options:

- GRAB_CURSOR to allow it to grab the mouse focus and
- BLOCKING to prevent anything else from using the cursor

Like this:

```
bl_options = {'GRAB_CURSOR', 'BLOCKING'}
```

More info in [the API documents](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bpy.types.Operator.html?highlight=grab_cursor).

As an example, you may see this in action in `blender/2.79/scripts/addons/mesh_extra_tools.py`

Comment: Nice find! This seems to be on the right track. There seems to be more to it than simply putting this in the bl_options line. The API says something about "enabling continuous grab".

Comment: This option means that the mouse events will still be sent to the operator, even if the mouse leaves the current editor, but you still need to enable continuous grab in preferences>input.

Comment: I tried to award you the bounty, but it says I have to wait 20 hours to do so.

Comment: The "enabling continuous grab" sentence threw me off as well. Turns out all I was missing was to add `BLOCKING`.